# I have 2 classes in a .ts file for Cypress which is being used through a cy. command how can I capture its logs through Jenkins in the console output

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have been tasked with making an SNS publisher message through the use of Cypress. Now I have it made and it actually works great, but when I put it into Jenkins it ceases to work. Now I want to get some logs for debugging going in the class which makes the publish calls and what not but the console.logs in that class do not seem to come up in the console output of Jenkins. I would like to mention that this class is called through a cy command. If you have any methods for getting the logs out that would be really helpful.

I tried creating a cy.task for logging but I get and error like [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#Cypress-detected-that-you-returned-a-promise-from-a-command-while-also-invoking-one-or-more-cy-commands-in-that-promise)

I tried to use `cy.log` but same issue as above.

I tried using `console.log` but it will not appear in the console output of Jenkins

Here is my script for getting the credentials from aws:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
/**
* @type {(config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions) => Promise<void>}
*/

module.exports = async (config) => {
  const AWS = require("aws-sdk")

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AWS.config.getCredentials((err, credentials) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error loading AWS credentials:", err)
        reject(err)
        return
      }

      if (!credentials || !credentials.accessKeyId) {
        console.error("No AWS credentials found.")
        reject(new Error("No AWS credentials found."))
        return
      }

      config.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials.accessKeyId
      config.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials.secretAccessKey
      config.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = credentials.sessionToken
      console.log(config.env)
      resolve({
        accessKeyId: credentials.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: credentials.secretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: credentials.sessionToken
      })
    })
  })
}
```

This is how I am publishing the SNS message:

```
    // Import required modules
import { SNSClient, PublishCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns"
const gen = require("../../../helpers/generateUUID")

class SnsLoader {
  private client: SNSClient

  constructor(region: string, accessKeyId: string, secretAccessKey: string, sessionToken?: string) {
    console.log("SNS loader region: " + region)
    this.client = new SNSClient({
      region,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: sessionToken
      }
    })
    console.log("Constructor Client" + JSON.stringify(this.client))
  }

  async publishToTopic(arnPrefix: string, topicName: string, messageObj: any): Promise<any> {
    const topicArn = `${arnPrefix}:${topicName}`
    console.log("Topic ARN: " + topicArn)
    const command = new PublishCommand({
      Message: JSON.stringify(messageObj),
      TopicArn: topicArn,
    })
    try {
      const response = await this.client.send(command)
      console.log(response)
      return { success: true, response }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in publishToTopic: ", error)
      return { success: false, error }
    }
  }
}
class SnsPublisher {
  private config: { region: string; environment: string; arnPrefix: string; }
  private sns: SnsLoader
  private topicName: string
  private messageType: string

  private getConfiguration(region: string, environment: string): { region: string; environment: string; arnPrefix: string } {
    const arnPrefix = `arn:aws:sns:${region}:${environment}`
    console.log("ARN Prefix: " + arnPrefix)
    return { region, environment, arnPrefix }
  }

  constructor(region: string, accessKeyId: string, secretAccessKey: string, environment: string, topicName: string, messageType: string, sessionToken?: string,) {
    this.config = this.getConfiguration(region, environment)
    this.sns = new SnsLoader(region, accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken)
    this.topicName = topicName
    this.messageType = messageType
  }

  async publishMessage(): Promise<any> {
    const message = {
      UtcTimestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      jiraKey: "AT-1", //Initiator: "Cypress"
      MessageType: this.messageType,
      BtCorrelationId: gen.generateUUID(),
      Environment: this.config.environment
    }
    console.log("Publishing message to SNS:", message)
    try {
      const response = await this.sns.publishToTopic(this.config.arnPrefix, this.topicName, message)
      console.log("Message sent to SNS:", response)
      return response
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error sending message:", err)
      throw err
    }
  }
}
export { SnsPublisher }
```

And here is how it is being made into a custom command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("publishSnsMessage", (params: { region: string; environment: string; topicName: string; messageType: string; }) => {
  const { region, environment, topicName, messageType } = params

  const accessKeyId = Cypress.env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
  const secretAccessKey = Cypress.env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
  const sessionToken = Cypress.env("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN") // This might be undefined

  const snsPublisher = new SnsPublisher(region, accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, environment, topicName, messageType, sessionToken)

  return snsPublisher.publishMessage()
})
```

So Jenkins gets the credentials completely fine I believe but when it comes to sending the message it fails out. Back to the beginning I would like to figure out ways to log whats happening when Jenkings makes use of the class and also figure out why this won't work

I tried creating a cy.task for logging but I get and error like [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#Cypress-detected-that-you-returned-a-promise-from-a-command-while-also-invoking-one-or-more-cy-commands-in-that-promise)

I tried to use `cy.log` but same issue as above.

I tried using `console.log` but it will not appear in the console output of Jenkins